# What does the author want to say about generators and relations in group theory? ("Algebra 1st Edition" by Michael Artin)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, relations, free-groups

I am reading "Algebra 1st Edition" by Michael Artin.
I want to know about generators and relations because I think I need to know about generators and relations when I use the GAP software.
But generators and relations are abstract and very difficult for me.

---

1. The author wrote "$\phi(w)=1$ or $w=1$ in $G$".
   Do we need "or $w=1$ in $G$"?
   I cannot understand what the author wants to say.

---

2. The author wrote:

> It might seem more systematic to require the defining relations to be generators for the group $N$. But remember that the kernel of the homomorphism $F\to G$ defined by a set of generators is always a normal subgroup, so there is no need to make the list of defining relations longer. If we know that some relation $r=1$ holds in $G$, then we can conclude that $grg^{-1}=1$ holds in $G$ too, simply by multiplying both sides of the equation on the left and right by $g$ and $g^{-1}$.

I cannot understand what the author wants to say in the above sentences.

Please explain what the author wants to say in the above sentences if possible.

---

Thank you.

---

[image]

Comment: GAP is perfectly happy with permutation groups -- you don't *have* to use groups given by generators and relators.

Comment: @ahulpke thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question 1, the sentence

> $\phi(w)=1$ or $w=1$ in $G$

is an explanation of an alternate notation, a notational abuse that is common in group theory. You can read this sentence like this:

> $\phi(w)=1$ or *[by abusing notation and regarding the letters in the word $w$ as actual elements of $G$, and then multiplying those elements together in the order given using the group operation of $G$]*  $w=1$ in $G$.

---

Regarding your question 2, the author is explaining what information one needs in order to completely specify a normal subgroup $N < F$ (and then the author applies that explanation that to the case that $N$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi : F \to G$).

For general subgroups, not assumed to be normal, one usually specifies a subgroup by listing a finite generating set for the subgroup. *[It might seem more systematic to require the defining relators to be generators for the group $N$].*

However, for a normal subgroup $N$, such as the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi : F \to G$, one does not need to list an entire generating set in order to determine $N$. *[But remember that the kernel of the homomorphism $F \mapsto G$ defined by a set of generators is always a normal subgroup, so there is no need to make the list of defining relators longer].*

One can instead list (what is usually) a much smaller set of elements $\{r_j \mid j \in J\} \subset N$ having the property that their set of conjugates $\{g r_j g^{-1} \mid j \in J, g \in G\}$ generates $N$. *[If we know that some relation $r=1$ holds in $G$, then we can conclude that $grg^{-1}=1$ holds in $G$ too, simply by multiplying both sides of the equation on the left and right by $g$ and $g^{-1}$]*

To summarize, one says that the set $\{r_j \mid j \in J\}$ **normally generates** $N$ if its set of conjugates generates $N$ in the ordinary sense. This is equivalent to saying that $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup in $G$ that contains the set $\{r_j \mid j \in J\}$, which is also equivalent to saying that $N$ is the intersection of all normal subgroups of $G$ that contain the set $\{r_j \mid j \in J\}$. So, when $N$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $F \mapsto G$, the condition on a set of relators in a presentation for $G$ is that the set normally generates $N$.

Comment: Lee Mosher, Thank you very much for your explanations.